# How to run a .sh script from R on Windows?

Tags: r, bash, shell

I need to run a .sh script from R on Windows.

To do this, I've tried to call the cygwin executable. Here is my code:

```
## Define the path to the script .sh and parameters
scriptPath <- "D:/script.sh"
parameters <- c("D:/test/results_","D:/test_text/results_","1","2")

## Define arguments
all_arguments <- c(scriptPath, parameters)

## Run the .sh script
command <- "C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe"
output <- system2(command, args=all_arguments, stdout=TRUE)
output
```

However, I have this error message: `"D:/script.sh: line 33: seq: command not found"`.

Here is the line 33:

```
for i in $(seq -f "%04g" $step $step $num_end);
```

On Linux, the script works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seq` is part of [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) so your first check should be if your Cygwin install has coreutils installed. You can find out how to install new packages on Cygwin [here](https://superuser.com/questions/304541/how-to-install-new-packages-on-cygwin).

`bash` under Cygwin will inherit the path from Windows and this doesn't include `/usr/bin`. To fix this, tell it to behave as if it is invoked at login

```
all_arguments <- c("-l", scriptPath, parameters)
```

Note that the filenames will need to be recognisable to Cygwin. See https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#cygdrive

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have installed the coreutils package but I have again the same error message.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have added `"-l"` in arguments but I have this error message: `[1] "/usr/bin/bash: script.sh: No such file or directory"
attr(,"status")
[1] 127`

Comment: Right - this is because cygwin refers to filenames such as `d:\my\file` as `/cygdrive/d/my/file`. Try changing your filenames to be cygdrive filenames and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now, I have this error message: `pvpython: command not found`. PvPython is the Python intreface to the ParaView application. However,  this application is installed on my computer.

Comment: Possibly a path problem? Again, your diagnosis steps should be to try from a bash shell and see if you can run the command from there. It may be unrelated and, if so, you need to ask a new question.

Comment: I don't know exactly where the path `export PATH="<C:/Program Files/ParaView 5.5.0-RC4-Qt5-Windows-64bit/bin/pvpython.exe>:$PATH"` must be added. In  `script.sh` ?

Comment: If pvpython is called from script.sh - yes but my guess is that you also need cygdrive name equivalents for the path.